# Slow mysql query--2 hours+

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, long-integer

Hello this is my query and is taking around an hour to complete. The table is 7 million records in innodb. I have an index on (timeStamp,symbol). Test7() is a function for coming up with previous week day.
I am using mysql 5.3. Any suggestions on how to speed this up? Thank you

'''''''''''

```
SELECT Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp,
Archive_dataPolygon.symbol,
Archive_dataPolygon.open,
Archive_dataPolygon.high,
Archive_dataPolygon.low,
Archive_dataPolygon.close,
Archive_dataPolygon.volume,
Archive_dataPolygon.afterHours,
Archive_dataPolygon.preMarket,
d2.timeStamp,
d2.symbol,
d2.open,
d2.high,
d2.low,
d2.close,
d2.volume,
d2.afterHours,
d2.preMarket,
d3.timeStamp,
d3.symbol,
d3.open,
d3.high,
d3.low,
d3.close,
d3.volume,
d3.afterHours,
d3.preMarket,
d4.timeStamp,
d4.symbol,
d4.open,
d4.high,
d4.low,
d4.close,
d4.volume,
d4.afterHours,
d4.preMarket,
round((Archive_dataPolygon.high-Archive_dataPolygon.open)/Archive_dataPolygon.open,3) as 'quoteChangePercent'

from Archive_dataPolygon
inner join Archive_dataPolygon d2 force index(timeStampSymbol) on d2.symbol=Archive_dataPolygon.symbol and d2.timeStamp = test7(Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp)
inner join Archive_dataPolygon d3 on d3.symbol=Archive_dataPolygon.symbol and d3.timeStamp = test7(d2.timeStamp)
inner join Archive_dataPolygon d4 on d4.symbol=Archive_dataPolygon.symbol and d4.timeStamp = test7(d3.timeStamp)

where Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp < NOW() - interval 4 day and Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 20000 DAY and Archive_dataPolygon.open >= 50 and Archive_dataPolygon.open <= 70 and Archive_dataPolygon.symbol not IN("%Nasdaq%") and round((Archive_dataPolygon.high-Archive_dataPolygon.open)/Archive_dataPolygon.open,3)=%quoteChangePercent%


HAVING isnull(Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp)=false and isnull(d2.timeStamp)=false and isnull(d3.timeStamp)=false and isnull(d4.timeStamp)=false

order by Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp desc
LIMIT 2000
```

'''''''''''''''

Comment: Functions cannot use indexes, so whatever `test7()` is, it's ruining performance (assuming that `timestamp` is indexed). `IN("%Nasdaq%")` cannot use an index; this would appear to be a flaw in your data model. And `%quoteChangePercent%` looks like an error.

Comment: `HAVING` is typically reserved for aggregate results, so I'm suspicious of its use here. `WHERE... IS NOT NULL` would be more usual.

Comment: And while it makes no difference to performance, there's no harm in aliasing ALL table instances.

Comment: And... your result set is difficult to use, as distinguishing between d2, d3, etc is tricky

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
d2.timeStamp = test7(Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp)
```

use

```
Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp = d2.timeStamp - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

or

```
d2.timeStamp = Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

(Try each way; I can't easily tell which would be better.)

I hope that `timeStamp` is of type "DATE".  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

There is no MySQL 5.3; perhaps you meant MariaDB 5.3?  Provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';`

This does no filtering, correct?  If not, leave it out:

```
Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 20000 DAY
```

What is this?

```
HAVING  isnull(d2.timeStamp)=false
```

It could (should) be simplified to

```
HAVING  d2.timeStamp IS NOT NULL
```

At that point, the test can be put into the `WHERE` clause (since you are using `JOIN` and not `LEFT JOIN`).

If you intended to have `LEFT JOIN` please elaborate on your goals.

This seems strange:

```
order by  Archive_dataPolygon.timeStamp desc LIMIT  2000
```

You want the very oldest records, regardless of symbol?

Normally I would recommend this order for the index: `(symbol, timeStamp)`.  In general, it is more optimal to use column(s) that are tested with `=` *first* in any composite index.  [However, it may not help performance for *this* query.]  Include two indexes.

The real killer is probably `test7()`.  I hope that after my other suggestions, it will touch only 2000 rows -- times 4 (due to the JOINs).

If you still need help after my suggestions, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT`.